# Python - Multiprocessing vs Multithreading for file-based work

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, os.walk

I have created a GUI (using wxPython) that allows the user to search for files and their content. The program consists of three parts:

1. The main GUI window
2. The searching mechanism (seperate class)
3. The output window that displays the results of the file search (seperate class)

Currently I'm using pythons `threading` module to run the searching mechanism (2) in a separate thread, so that the main GUI can still work flawlessly. I'm passing the results during runtime to the output window (3) using `Queue`. This works fine for less performance requiring file-reading-actions, but as soon as the searching mechanism requires more performance, the main GUI window (1) starts lagging.

This is roughly the schematic:

```
import threading
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame): # this is point (1)
    def __init__(self, parent, ...):
        # Initialize frame and panels etc.

        self.button_search = wx.Button(self, label="Search")
        self.button_search.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSearch)

    def onSearch(self, event):
        """Run filesearch in separate Thread""" # Here is the kernel of my question
        filesearch = FileSearch().Run()
        searcher = threading.Thread(target=filesearch, args=(args,))
        searcher.start()


class FileSearch(): # this is point (2)
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def Run(self, args):
        """Performs file search"""
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...):
            for file in files:
                ...

    def DetectEncoding(self):
        """Detects encoding of file for reading"""
        ...


class OutputWindow(wx.Frame): # this is point (3)
    def __init__(self, parent, ...):
        # Initialize output window
        ...

    def AppendItem(self, data):
        """Appends a fileitem to the list"""
        ...
```

**My questions:**

1. Is python's `multiprocessing` module better suited for this specific performance requiring job?
2. If yes, which way of interprocess communication (IPC) should I choose to send the results from the searching mechanism class (2) to the output window (3) and how should implement it schematically?

Comment: Depends on what your 'FileSearch' is actually doing - if it's just I/O then just let your search thread yield a bit of the time to the rest of the system (i.e. `time.sleep(0.1)` after each directory searched or so). If there is some heavy processing involved as well, then go with a separate process as while GIL will let threaded I/O operations run in parallel, it won't be so lenient with actual processing.

Comment: @zwer Thanks for the answer. So you say processing will not make that big of a noticable difference? What do you mean by _if it's just I/O then just let your search thread yield a bit of the time to the rest of the system (i.e. time.sleep(0.1)_?